# Databasemodels to MVC models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I used LINQ (DatabaseDataContext) to create models to use in my business layer. Currently I'm writing ViewModels (because data from the database, like IDs, is irrelevant for my view and thus not needed in the ViewModels + I want to keep the MVC and the business layer seperated.

```
namespace alina1617.Models
{
    public class GebruikerViewModel
    {
        String Gebruikersnaam { get; set; }
        String Wachtwoord { get; set; }
        FaculteitViewModel Faculteit { get; set; }
        InstellingViewModel instelling { get; set; }

    }

    public class FaculteitViewModel
    {
        String Naam { get; set; }
    }                                                                                     

    public class InstellingViewModel
    {
        String naam { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is part of the database model:

```
private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

private int _ID;

private string _Gebruikersnaam;

private string _Wachtwoord;

private int _InstellingID;

private int _FaculteitenID;

private EntitySet<ZoekresultaatWerkvorm> _ZoekresultaatWerkvorms;

private EntitySet<ZoekresultaatArchetype> _ZoekresultaatArchetypes;

private EntitySet<ZoekresultaatFaciliteitFixed> _ZoekresultaatFaciliteitFixeds;

private EntitySet<ZoekresultaatFaciliteitLo> _ZoekresultaatFaciliteitLos;

private EntitySet<ZoekresultaatParameter> _ZoekresultaatParameters;

private EntityRef<Faculteiten> _Faculteiten;

private EntityRef<Instelling> _Instelling;
```

So I what I've already written correct? i'm planning on using automapper to then map between the two. I still have a ton of code to write so I'd like to know whether I'm on the right track of if I'm doing something wrong here?

Comment: Completely irrelevant to the question, but I would recommend writing your code in English at all times. I had this problem where I wrote my code in Dutch and had to translate all of it when an English speaking developer joined my team. Just a thing to think about ^^

Comment: Thanks, I usually do but there is 0 possibility of anyone else joining this project and my teammates are Dutch and are even worse programmers than I am so I just wrote it in Dutch :)

Comment: Separating Data Model and View Models is a commonly used practice. As well as using Automapper for the mapping. So yes you are in the good track

Comment: @Juan And when you look at my model, they way I'm doing it is correct?

Comment: @user3227070 even then it's a good idea to keep it in English. This is a good example, since a very small portion of users on SO speak Dutch. It's not necessary, but it's just a good habit to get used to.

Comment: @user3227070 yest loks fine I think, hard to tell being in Dutch. You may end up needing to pass your Ids to the view anyway as well in order to know what the view is talking about when it does new requests

Comment: @Juan Okay, thanks. My names are also unique so I think it that case it should be fine? Will see though.